# Can make queue notification using Service?

Tags: android, service

I'm making queue notification using service.
Here is my code.

```
   serviceIntent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
                serviceIntent.setAction(MyService.BACKGROUND);
                context.startService(serviceIntent);


   if (BACKGROUND.equals(intent.getAction())) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Background", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startForeground(NOTI_ID++, getNoti());
    }
       Toast.makeText(this, "onStartCommand", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return START_STICKY;
```

Comment: what is `queue notification`? What is the problem?

Comment: please elaborate more